# Scrape multiple pages through pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape multiple pages but they will give the result of only the end  page these are page link https://www.baroul-cluj.ro/tabloul-avocatilor/avocati-definitivi/

```
import pandas as pd

for page in range(1,26):
    df=pd.read_html('https://www.baroul-cluj.ro/tabloul-avocatilor/avocati-definitivi/?wpv_view_count=9662&wpv_post_search=&wpv_paged={page}'.format(page=page))
    df[0].to_csv('tab.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you always write to the same file, so you will only get the last scrapped data.

A solution to your problem is to create a new file every time like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

for page in range(1,26):
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.baroul-cluj.ro/tabloul-avocatilor/avocati-definitivi/?wpv_view_count=9662&wpv_post_search=&wpv_paged={page}'.format(page=page))
    df[0].to_csv(f"tab-{page}.csv",index=False)
```

Or if you want a single file, you can use append mode when writing the CSV file.

```py
import pandas as pd

for page in range(1,26):
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.baroul-cluj.ro/tabloul-avocatilor/avocati-definitivi/?wpv_view_count=9662&wpv_post_search=&wpv_paged={page}'.format(page=page))
    df[0].to_csv('tab.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

- `mode="a"`: Use the **append** mode as opposed to `w` – the default **write** mode.
- `index=False`: Do not include an index column when appending the new data.
- `header=False`: Do not include a header when appending the new data.

**NOTE:** Be sure that **the file exist** to use the append mode.

Comment: I want `1 CSVfile` only in which all data are stored they give CSV for each page

Comment: See updated solution for one file.

Comment: problem are not solve they are making csv  for each page

Comment: Ah! Sorry! I forgot something on the example. Please re-check the solution now.

Comment: they also print some duplicate value how to deal it

Comment: You need to investigate the origin of the duplicated data first. Is it from the website ? Or your script ? Maybe if it's originate from the website, you need to do some post-processing on your code.